# Does python redefine guess of variable scope inside function?

Tags: python, function, scope, global, local-variables

I have a simple example that is confusing me, concerning local and global scopes in functions.

```
a=1
def func():
    print(a)   # Error: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
    a=2
    print(a)

func()
```

If I comment the first print statement it runs fine. The local "a" takes precedence over the global "a" and hence 2nd print gives 2.

If I comment the a=2, then the print statements in the local scope see the global scope and print a=1.

What is confusing me is that when I run the entire function python throws an error: "local variable 'a' referenced before assignment"

What I was expecting was that the first print(a) produces 1 and the second print(a) produces 2.

I'm struggling to tease this apart. I examined locals() inside the func() so the first print function sees no local but it does see a global a. I'm really a bit lost and would appreciate someone explaining why it appears that the combination errors when the individual bits work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you make an assignment to `a` variable in a scope, it becomes **local to that scope** and shadows any similarly named variable in the outer scope. Since Python's scoping is static, wheter `a` is local or global is determined at **compile time** and that's why, when it comes to `func()`, Python sees `a` is assigned within the function body and treats it as a local variable **throughout the entire function**. Note at this point it's irrelevant where in the function body this happen exactly - it's sufficient for Python to just know it does. When you try to `print(a)` before **local** `a` has been really assigned a value **within that function**, you will face an error. When you comment out `a = 2` however, then local `a` is gone, and Python sees one from global scope, therefore `print(a)` executes successfully as the `a` at that point is assigned a value.

Comment: Interesting ! Is there a way to get unassigned locals ? Because they does not show in `locals()`

Comment: There's no way I know of to get unassigned local variables because they technically don't exist yet. A variable is only "born", so to speak, when it gets a value assigned to it for the first time. Before that, it's just a name that Python doesn't know about.

Comment: @Viper why do you want to get unassigned locals? is your goal to find safe names to use for locals without shadowing globals accidentally?

Comment: No. Assignments *create* the variable; there's no such thing as an unassigned variable in Python.

Comment: I'd say whatever the reason, using global variables (regardless the language) is almost always as good idea as poking hornet's nest with a stick. They will eventually come after you.

Comment: No that was just pure curiosity, since Python does know the name "a" is in local scope, I was wondering if this info was accessible live in the code

Comment: *Mutating* global variables is the bad idea.

Comment: I agree using globals is never a great idea I was just trying to understand scopes correctly and then what I thought I knew didn't seem to work. Thanks for the answer will mark as such

Comment: @MikeSmith the key is to realize that when you `def` a function, Python gets to see the whole thing before it executes a single line of it.  It knows that a variable will be assigned so it should be local in scope rather than global.